# fcbkcomplete does not post

Tags: django, forms, autocomplete

I want to populate the recipients field of a message form using FCBKComplete. The client-side works fine. FCBKComplete gets the options and writes the selected one into the recipients field. But when the form is posted, the POST data does not have the values in the recipients field.

The server-side is Django:

```
def recipients_autocomplete(request):
    q = request.GET.get('tag')
    dump = ''
    if q:
        users = User.objects.filter(username__startswith=q)
        results = [{"key": u.username, "value": u.username} for u in users]
        dump = json.dumps(results)
    return HttpResponse(dump, mimetype="text/plain")
```

The recipients is empty in the `request.POST` dictionary:

```
{...
 u'recipients[]': [u'']
 ...}
```

How can I can get the values in the autocompleted field?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you narrow down where in the view it's failing? Is it the "if q", in which case the request isn't getting a 'tag'. Can you check with firebug what the client is sending as a request? Is it really a GET? Or is it a POST?

Comment: this view is not failing. it works, the field is populated as it should with the values provided by this view but when the form is posted, the POST dictionary does not have the values in the autocomplete field. thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that in my Django form the recipients is a `CharField` but fcbkComplete expects a `select` field. I changed the type of recipients in the form definition to `ChoiceField` and now the values are POSTed.

Another thing is the `[]` appended to the attribute name. To avoid that, I used this patch:
https://github.com/eeabed/FCBKcomplete/commit/00183fbd83283cf05b3c9de02e076201623975dd

Thanks.